# Validating Unique Entry?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm kind of surprised this is not covered in any documentation that I've read, or I've simply overlooked it. Validating unique entries seems like something that should be common place.

When creating a new entry from a form, what is the preferred method of checking uniqueness of the member?

```
val memberForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long]),
      "membername" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> email,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Member.apply)(Member.unapply)
)
```

Is the preferred method to create a custom validator?

```
val validateMember(name: String, email: String) = {
    // check unique name & email
}
```

Or should this be done some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this wasn't the greatest question, since I believe it was simply a case of me over-thinking the problem and not really understanding the issue. The solution I came up with was pretty straight forward:

```
val memberForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long]),
      "membername" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> email,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText
)(Member.apply)(Member.unapply)
  verifying ("Member already exists!", m => Member.findByName(m.membername).isEmpty)
  verifying ("Email already exists!", m => Member.findByName(m.email).isEmpty)
)
```

Where `Member.findByName()` has logic in it to determine if it's looking at an email or a standard membername.

This probably isn't a good Question and Answer, so if anyone with the power to delete it feel free.

Answer (score 1):

I usually like to think about that as a business logic thing rather than validation (since it involves talking to a database). If you agree about that then it might be a better fit to place the uniqueness check logic in the controller after reading the form data into an instance of `Member`.

You could still reshow the page with the form with an error if it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. But I think my question was bad. I kind of did something similar in my answer.